# How do I download attached files over HTTP using Java?

Tags: java, http

I am trying to download a file given a URL. However, the file is 'attached' in the header, in the form:

Content-Disposition : attachment; filename=x.csv

What is the best way of doing this in Java? I have tried using URLConnection, but have only been able to retrieve the actual header details with this.

Thank you - any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [HttpClient framework](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) for special tricks.